Can Bob send a stone into Alice's future?
I tried to apply the following principles:

Leading clocks lag: it is the principle that when a set of clocks is moving past an observer, the leading clock will lag behind the trailing clock.

Time of the moving runs slower than the rested as according to the rested.

To each observer all of his clocks are always synchronized to him.

The photo clock principle


to a specific situation:
Consider a long spaceship with Alice on it whose right most point starts moving from the origin at t=0, towards the right. At the origin, we have Bob, stationary.
Let there be two clocks on the spaceship, one at the right most point C1, one a little behind it, C2.
At say 10ns for Bob, C1 will read 5ns, C2 will read 9ns, to Bob.
Also, say, at this point , C1 (and thus C2 also) reads 6ns to Alice.
At C2 let there be a particle emitter and it emits a particle now i.e. at 9ns ( as according to Bob ).
For Alice, her time is still at 6ns, so the particle emitter hasn't yet emitted the particle but will emit it after 3ns.
So the future of Alice's particle emitter is known to Bob. Is this correct?

What does "leading clocks lag" mean?

@WillO , I have included it in the question.

I'm not sure I understand all the details of the question, but regarding the title: It is generally much easier to send messages  into people's future than into their past! ;-)

@Peter-ReinstateMonica :-) :-)!

@SX849 I'm glad you are happy ;-). But the question remains: The last sentence seems to indicate that you have the idea that Bob receives information from the future, which is much more remarkable (because receiving from the future implies sending into the past, the opposite of what the title asks). Is the title not expressing what you want to ask? Am I misunderstanding it?

No I don't think you have misunderstood it ... Yes the title is actually a wrong description of the question...Thanks for pointing it out :)

I think what you really want to do here is to take Alice and Bob as inertial reference frames rather than two individual worldlines (don't confuse these two concepts).
I say that because that is the only way to make sense of Bob being able to simultaneously (in his frame) observe, what two spatially separated clocks in Alice's frame measure.
Given that, it seems like the "paradox" you're trying to imply is that there is some instant when Bob knows more about Alice's future than Alice. But the italicized text is exactly where your logic breaks down: Alice and Bob don't have a shared notion of simultaneity.
Therefore your final statement

So the future of Alice's particle emitter is known to Bob.

lacks meaning.
This answer might seem to be at odds with the one given by Dale, but it isn't. Because, let's suppose that the specific observer in Bob's frame who sees the emitter going off at $t_{\text{alice}}=9 {\text{ns}}$ wants to communicate it somehow to Alice. Now again, Alice is a frame, not a specific observer. The specific "Alice-observer" at the point $C_2$ will already know that the emitter went off, because this observer was right "on top" of the emitter all along.
On the other hand, if you try to communicate that information to $C_1$, in an attempt to "communicate information to the past", you'll be faced exactly with the delay issue Dale pointed out in the aforementioned answer.
So that ultimately, you'll find that you can't communicate information from the future back to the past, and that any apparent "future information" you seem to possess, is already present in the specific spacetime point in the other frame as well. Which is just a long-winded way to reiterate, that this apparent "paradox" is based on a misunderstanding of the relativity of simultaneity, which I hope this answer helps to clarify.

I understood your explanation, thanks. But suppose there are infinite stationary observers all along the axis. Each of them are at synchronised times according to each other. Now say all of them take a photo right where they are, of the spaceship of Alice. Now these photos are absolute (as there is no second spatial dimension, light from the cameras don't have to travel at all. Each of the cameras will take the photo of Alice's spaceship right where the camera is). Won't all the various photos show instances of Alice's spaceship's past and future. This is because when these photos were taken,

all of Alice's clocks were fixed at one time value, for Alice.

@SX849 Sure, we better not think of photos because that again makes us think of light delays, etc :) but I see what you're getting at: the thing is, that if you later go and question the "Alice axis", all of the Alice-observers will testify that they got photographed at a different time. So no, it wasn't fixed at one time value for Alice, that's exactly a manifestation of the relativity of simultaneity: In the Alice frame, all the photos were taken at different times, although Bob was very careful to have everyone snap them at exactly 12:00 o'clock by his clocks :)

Is the point that I'm missing that even if one particular Bob knows one point of Alice's spaceship's future, this information cannot be told to Alice?

@SX849 Again, There is an "Alice" at the same spacetime point, and she already knows. Now if you try to move that information to a Bob that you think still has access to a "past Alice", you'll find you can't do it, not any faster than just the same Alice who was at the same spacetime point can propagate that information as well. So you can impart no special knowledge to Alice about her own future, by moving relatively to the her frame.

@SX849 You're welcome

Imagine a long line of cameras in Bob's frame and a long line of clocks in Alice's spaceship. At some instant in Bob's frame, all the cameras click and each takes a photo of the most adjacent clock- all of the photos will show different times. In Bob's frame the simultaneous camera clicks will be a long sequence of clicks in Alice's frame. Incidentally, that's how length contraction arises. Alice sees bob's cameras start by taking a picture of the front of her ship...

...and gradually work their way along taking successive photos of the rest. Of course, by the time the camera nearest the rear of the ship clicks, the rear of the ship has moved forward from the point it was at when the front of the ship was photographed, hence the ship seems shorter in Bob's frame.

Yes I understood... Thank you for the clarification :).


So the future of Alice's particle emitter is known to Bob. Is this correct?

No. Bob can only know the status of the particle emitter after a time $\Delta t= d/c$ where $d$ is the distance of the light path between Bob and the particle emitter. That will not happen before Alice learns about it in any frame.

This might be obvious but I'm not very sure: can $d = 0$? That is there is a stationary Bob everywhere on the axis.

Sure, then Alice and the d=0 Bob are colocated at the event of the emission and they both learn of it at the same time. There is never any frame where any Bob learns of it before Alice
